# Google Tag Manager console error after removing unsafe-eval from CSP header

Tags: security, web-applications, google-tag-manager, content-security-policy

We need to remove `unsafe-eval` from the Content Security Policy header in our application for security reasons. But after removing it, we get a console error saying

> call to eval() or related function blocked by CSP

We have added "https://www.googletagmanager.com" domain to the `script-src` as well, but still it prompts the error.

Is there a way only to allow `unsafe-eval` for Google tag manager domain? Or will there be any other alternative?

Sample Analytic code snippet is below that we use in our script

```
(function (w, d, s, l, i) {
    w[l] = w[l] || []; w[l].push({
        'gtm.start':
            new Date().getTime(), event: 'gtm.js'
    }); var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
            j = d.createElement(s), dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : ''; j.async = true; j.src =
                '//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl; f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
})(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', 'GTM-123456');
```

Answer (score 3):

According to [this Lunametrics article](http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2015/02/12/reuse-code-return-functions/) GTM uses eval for custom javascript variables:

> [...] your scripts may execute a little more slowly as a result, since there
>   will now be an additional eval() for the Custom JavaScript Variable
>   that you are passing your arguments to

In fact when I add a custom JS variable to a container that did not have any before the following piece of code is added to the gtm.js file:

```
// Copyright 2012 Google Inc. All rights reserved.
// Container Version: QUICK_PREVIEW
(function(w,g){w[g]=w[g]||{};w[g].e=function(s){return eval(s);};})(window,'google_tag_manager');(function(){

var __c;__c=function(a){return a["39"]};__c.a="c";__c.b=["google"];__c.isVendorTemplate=!0;
```

(Notice the use of eval in the first line after the comment).

So I suspect that removing unsafe-eval *might* work if you can do without custom javascript variables.

Comment: I have updated the post by including the code snippet that we use for tag manager. Not sure whether we can go with your suggestion.

Comment: To avoid confusion - I do not suggest that you add any code, I was pointing out  that Google *automatically* adds eval calls to the gtm.js file if you are using custom javascript variables. So the suggest would be rather to try if your csp works in a container without custom javascript variables and if so, to see if you can do somehow without them.

Comment: I have updated the question by including the javascript code that I used and it is in the _layout file.